# Is there information available about an aircraft incident from New York to LHR in 2004?

Tags: incidents

I am attempting to find some form of incident log regarding a flight I took i 2004 (I believe May/June).  I believe it was a British Airways flight but it may have been operated by another airline.

I was on a flight from New York (I think JFK) to LHR when we had to divert to a runway in Bangor, Maine due to a cockpit fire, I seem to recall being caused by an Air Conditioning Unit.

I can't seem to find any details online about this incident.  Does anyone know of any resources I could use to locate this?  It was in the Bangor Daily News at the time but I've searched their site and can't find any info.

It seems to me that this wasn't "major" enough of an incident to be on any main logs, etc.

Comment: Do you know what airline at least? The NTSB database doesn't show any accidents/incidents at BGR (other than a 208 Hard Landing in 2003) from 2000 to 2006.

Comment: Concorde? http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=212653 (I'm guessing you would remember if a) it was going the other way and b) it had a very pointy nose cone)

Comment: Ha - No pointy nose and I was definitely flying home to the UK.  I'll try to dig out some more info and update the question.  I took photos of the fire engines so if I can find them I can find the date.

Comment: It seems (froma bit of googling) that Bangor is a very popular place for diversions between JFK and LHR. Any more detail you can provide may help narrow it down a bit

Comment: I have narrowed the date down to May-June 2004.

Comment: @Ste - just realised who you are from 12s/WH days from your avatar!!

Comment: @Jamiec And now I know who you are!  Small world!  The flight in question was coming back from the 12s meet in NYC!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here it is: [British Airways flight diverted to Bangor](http://archive.bangordailynews.com/2004/06/10/british-airways-flight-diverted-to-bangor-2/).

> At about 8 p.m. British Airways Flight 112, traveling from John F. Kennedy International Airport in New York City to Heathrow Airport in London, diverted to Bangor after smoke was discovered in the cockpit.

Story was published on June 10<sup>th</sup>, 2004. Article says Wednesday night, so it should have happened on June 9<sup>th</sup>.

Both the [AAIB](https://www.gov.uk/aaib-reports) and the NTSB don't have any reports. It must have been a minor issue. Just a [BA 777 on the same day](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/england/london/3939455.stm), fuel leak on departing Heathrow.

Comment: Perfect!  Is there a "severity scale" for reporting to the AAIB or NTSB?  Happy to ask or be pointed to another question.

Comment: @Ste severity of an incident would indeed be a good question.

Comment: Good find, sir! You are a master of Google Fu! +1

Comment: For the NTSB you are required to report accidents/incidents per 49 CFR 830.10   http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=39bb924986902a073ef174341af7688c&rgn=div5&view=text&node=49:7.1.4.1.12&idno=49 using NTSB Form 6120.1  http://www.ntsb.gov/Documents/6120_1web_Reader.pdf